# Can not get the posted value of CKeditor in Php

Tags: php, ckeditor

Here how I created CKeditor in index.php(I am using it with CKfinder):

```
< textarea id="text" name="text" >

< /textarea >

       <?php
        include_once 'ckeditor/ckeditor.php';
        require_once 'ckfinder/ckfinder.php' ;
        $ckeditor = new CKEditor();
        $ckeditor->basePath  = 'ckeditor/' ;
        CKFinder::SetupCKEditor( $ckeditor, 'ckfinder/' ) ;
        $config['height'] = '300';
        $ckeditor->editor('text', $initialValue, $config);
        ?>
```

and submit the value of the editor via this button to the ajax function below:

(  `< a onclick="submit();" > Send < /a >   == >` this perfectly calls the ajax function)

```
 function submit()
    {
    var textbox= CKEDITOR.instances.text.getData();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index2.php",
            data: "textbox="+textbox,
            error: function(){

              alert('Error while loading');
          },
                success: function(data){
                $('#content').html(data);
      }
      });
}
```

In index2.php I tried to get the value as

```
   $textbox= $_POST['textbox'];
```

and it did not work. I also tried to get it via

```
   $textbox= stripslashes($_POST['textbox']) ;
   $textbox=mysql_real_escape_string($textbox);
```

İt also did not work. I do not know what to do with this issue. Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: CKEDITOR.instances is an array, you may want something like: CKEDITOR.instances[0]

Comment: The function submit gets the value perfectly with                           var textbox= CKEDITOR.instances.text.getData();                                            the problem actually happens in index2.php, a blank value shows up.

Comment: Normally I submit data like this: data: {textbox: 'xxxx'}, it's safer than a string as you don't need to care about encoding issues.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example of that usage. Did you mean:                                                               function submit()
    {
    var textbox= CKEDITOR.instances.text.getData();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index2.php",
            data: {textbox:textbox},
            error: function(){

              alert('Error while loading');
          },
                success: function(data){
                $('#content').html(data);
      }
      });
}                                                                         Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem with CKEditor and posting it's values when those values contained special characters..
in my case it happened when a `&nbsp;` was inside the content of the editor.
It "killed" the url since `?data=blabla&nbsp;` is a malformed url..
i used encodeURIComponent() to make sure such things wouldn't happen.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

not sure if this is exactly your problem (right now ;) but you might want to look for this too.

Comment: Thank you so much Gung, that fixed my problem. It is now working properly.